# Is the matrix $\mu_f(X_i \cap X_j)$ positive definite?

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, metric-embeddings

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be finite subsets of some larger finite set $Z$.

Let $f:Z \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be any function, and define a (counting) measure $\mu_f(X) = \sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ for a finite subset $X \subset Z$.
For instance $f(x) = 1 $ would correspond to $\mu_f(X) = |X|$.

Is the matrix $\mu_f(X_i \cap X_j)$ positive definite?

- For the case $f(x)=1$ and $X_i = \{1,\ldots,i\}$ we get $\mu_f(X_i \cap X_j)= \min(i,j)$ which is known to be positive definite.
- For the case $f(x)=1$ and $X_i = \{ i/k | 1 \le k \le j \}$ we get $\mu_f(X_i \cap X_j ) = \gcd(i,j)$ which is known to be positive definite.
- For the case $f(x)=x^k$, $k=0,1,2,\cdots$ and $X_i = \{ d | j \equiv 0 \mod d \}$ we get $\mu_f(X_i \cap X_j ) = \sigma_k(\gcd(i,j))$ which I think it is positive definite, but have no proof for this, where $\sigma_k(n) = \sum_{d|n}d^k$ is the sum of divisors.

By embedding the subsets $X_i$ to a vector $\phi_f(X_i)$ we see, that the quantity

$\mu_f(X_i \cap X_j) = <\phi(X_i),\phi(X_j)>$ is a dot-product, hence the matrix is a Gram matrix. Hence it is enough to show, what the vectors $\phi(X_i)$ are linearly independent or that the Gram matrix has $\det \neq 0$ to prove that the Gram matrix is positive definite.

The embedding $\phi$ can done in this way:

By listing the elements of $Z$ in an ordered way and the vector $\phi(X)$ is a vector with the $i$-th entry $=\sqrt{f(x)}$ if $z_i \in X$ and $0$ otherwise.

Why should this be interesting:

I think by using this construction, one is able to define (if the answer is positive) Kernels $K_f(i,j) = \mu_f(X_i \cap X_j)$ for example $=\sigma_k(\gcd(i,j))$ or $\min(i,j)$ or $\gcd(i,j)$ on natural numbers and apply techniques of machine learning for natural numbers, for example.

Of course the sets do not have to be for natural numbers it could be for other things as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This matrix is always positive semi definite, but without further conditions on the $X_i$ it can fail to be invertible. One possible condition that guarantees invertibility is that each $X_i$ is not contained in the union of all $X_j$ with $j<i$ (this is satisfied in all your examples).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @GjergjiZaimi